# Get users whose last 2 orders were this month and 2 months ago

Tags: mysql, sql

In MySQL, is it possible to get a list of users who ordered this month, but only those whose previous order was several months ago? For example, getting users who ordered this March and whose previous order was way back on December of last year.

I've been trying to formulate a query but I admit this is beyond me.

### Update

Here's a modified query based on @Jitendra's answer but it doesn't show the right values:

```
-- Checks users who ordered this month and whose last order was Dec 2015
SELECT a.id, a.created FROM orders AS a
    JOIN (SELECT id, created FROM orders WHERE DATE_FORMAT(created, '%Y-%m') = '2015-12') AS b 
        ON a.id = b.id AND a.created = b.created
    WHERE DATE_FORMAT(a.created, '%Y-%m') = '2016-03'
    ORDER BY a.id DESC
```

For some reason it shows empty results based on my sample data.

Comment: show us your table structure

Answer (score 3):

you can write two queries and then have inner join on both like

select a.* from orders where orderdate > <> as a inner join (select b.orderdate from orders where orderdate <= <>)

in you case query will be

```
select a.* from orders where a.orderdate >= '2016-03-01' as a 
inner join 
(select b.orderdate from orders where orderdate <= '2015-12-31') as b 
ON a. orderid = b.orderid
```

I think this should solve your problem.

Comment: There was an error but I got it to work after rewriting it, but It didn't show the values I wanted. Here it is I posted it on the top.

Comment: would suggest you add userid column instead of fullname and then do join on userid col.

Answer (score 0):

```
select o.id, 
       sum(when case o.created>'2016-03-01' then 1 else 0 end) as current_count,
       sum(when case o.created<='2016-03-01' then 1 else 0 end) as prev_count
from orders o
group by o.id
having current_count>0 and prev_count>0
```

corrected

Comment: Don't you mean:

`SELECT o.id, 
        SUM(CASE WHEN DATE_FORMAT(o.created, '%Y-%m') = '2016-03' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) current_count,
        SUM(CASE WHEN DATE_FORMAT(o.created, '%Y-%m') = '2015-12' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) prev_count
 FROM sl_orders o
 GROUP BY o.id
 HAVING current_count > 0 AND prev_count > 0`

But it doesn't seem to work right.

Comment: yes. I posted before you committed your query adn then corrected **created** only. In fact we get 2 counts - count of orders this month and count of orders before this month. If both >0 we got the user